# What data type I should use for versioning?

Tags: c#, data-structures

Is there data type for software version in C#? I would like to be able to easily compare 5.02.0002.2 and 5.02.0003.0 (which one is higher).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at [System.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx), it does exactly what you want and is used by .NET assemblies as well.

Comment: It's worth noting that `System.Version` doesn't support components with leading zeroes. e.g. `new Version("5.02.0003.0") == new Version("5.2.3.0")`

Comment: +1. @p.s.w.g if someone considers `0003` and `3` to be significantly different I'd be seriously concerned about such person :) (good point otherwise, I guess it simply parses `int` values between dots...)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah, I just wanted to point that out, mostly for OP's benefit, to avoid any confusion that might arise when he goes to use it.